# Call collect on partial function as member of an object

Tags: list, scala

I am using some functions that return Options, but I would like to replace them by PartialFunctions in order to use the collect function in Scala. In detail I am trying to call collect (and collectFirst) on a list of objects that contain a partial function in the following way:

```
class A(val bs : List[B]) {
    def getAll(i : Int): List[Int] = bs.map(_.foo(i))
}

class B(val y : Int) {
    val foo : PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
        case x if x > y => y
    }
}
```

The above code compiles and does what I want to if the function foo is defined for all values in bs.

```
val a = new A(List(new B(1), new B(2), new B(3)));
println(a.getAll(5))
```

prints "List(1, 2, 3)", but of course I run into an error if foo is not defined for a value. Hence, I want to replace it by "collect"

```
def getAll(i : Int): List[Int] = bs.collect(_.foo(i))
```

In my understanding collect should work pretty much the same as map, yet still the above code does not compile (I get a type mismatch because foo cannot be resolved). What is the best way in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collect` expects to receive a partial function (not a function or lambda), that will take an element of your collection as an input: `PartialFunction[B, Int]`. But here you want just to call your `PartialFunction[Int, Int]` inside another function, so you don't even passing a `PartialFunction` into `collect` (you're passing function `(_.foo(i)): B => Int`).

Solution without `collect` (but still with `PartialFunction` as a member of `B`):

```
def getAll(i : Int): List[Int] = bs.flatMap(_.foo.lift(i))
```

`lift` rises your function from `PartialFunction[Int, Int]` to `Int => Option[Int]` here.

If you really really want to `collect`:

```
import Function._
def getAll(i : Int): List[Int] = bs.collect(unlift(_.foo.lift(i)))
```

`unlift` reduces `B => Option[Int]` into `PartialFunction[B, Int]`

The ugliest version is `collect{ case x if x.foo.isDefinedAt(i) => x.foo(i) }`

Better solution is to move your partial function outside of `B`:

```
case class A(bs : List[B]) {
    def getAll(x : Int): List[Int] = bs.collect {
       case B(y) if x > y => y
    }
}

case class B(val y : Int)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The ugliest version is actually the one I came up with in the beginning, yet then I thought that this is too ugly :) I am also interested in collectFirst. How could I do that?

Comment: Already found the solution (I use the solution that you labeled "better solution"). Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Anyway, in some other situation, you can do that the same way: `bs.collectFirst(unlift(_.foo.lift(i)))`. `bs.flatMap(_.foo.lift(i)).headOption` will return same result, but traverses all collection, if it's not lazy (iterator, view or stream are lazy, but list isn't)